# Find the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $Y=y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variable with density 
$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{y}, & \text{for } 0<x<y<1, \\[8pt] 0, & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$.

To find the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $Y=y$ first I calculated:
$f_Y(y)=\int_0^y \frac{1}{y}dx = 1 $ for $0<y<1 $.
Then $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\begin{cases} \frac{\frac{1}{y}}{1},  & \text{for } 0<x<y<1, \\[8pt] 0, & \text {otherwise.} \end{cases}$.
Is that correct? I am very unsure about that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just like for 2 events $A,B$ you have 
$$\mathbb{P}[A|B] = \frac{\mathbb{P}[A \cap B]}{\mathbb{P}[B]}$$
so too more generally in terms of random variables,
$$
f_{X|Y}(x,y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}
$$

Comment: Is $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ already the conditional distribution? Or is it only the conditional density and I have to integrate $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$?

Comment: @tommy_m Not sure what you mean by conditional distribution. The usual notation denotes the pdf as $f(\cdot)$ and the cdf as $F(\cdot)$, both can characterize the distribution, and so can the mgf $M_X(t)$...

To be specific, in this case $f_{X|Y}(x,y)$ denotes the conditional pdf of $X$ given $Y$, but if you need the conditional cdf, you would indeed need to integrate it.